# Join entre tabelas que não se relacionam diretamente

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, join, modelo-relacional

Tenho três tabelas:

1. Candidato que tem um ID como pk (que foi inventado)
2. Inscrição que tem FK para Candidato
3. ENEM que não tem nenhum id que represente o candidato, só a inscrição dele e informações como cor/raça, município

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso trazer essa PK_Candidato na tabela Inscrição fazendo um JOIN com a tabela Enem, mas como fazer isso se Candidato e Enem não estão relacionadas diretamente por um código único, apenas por informações que se repetem como sexo?

Tentei relacionar Candidato e Enem por uma outra tabela que ambas têm em comum, que seria Município, mas também não obtive o resultado esperado, que seria o número da inscrição sem repetição seguido dos dados desejados.

Comment: As tabelas devem se relacionar de algum modo. Qual é o modelo relacional do banco de dados? Possuí DER?

Comment: Possui um MER que está no db designer (só consigo compartilhar por e-mail). A única tabela que relacionaria as duas seria a de Município, porque a tabela Enem tem cod_municipio e a Candidato tem FK pra municipio.  Fora essa tabela, elas tem dados em comum, mas que se repetem entre os registros...

Comment: Você deve fazer entao um inner join com as tres tabelas então.

Comment: http://firebase.com.br/pipermail/lista_firebase.com.br/2004-December/004057.html , creio que o join implicito resolva candidato-->incricao--->enem

Comment: @RORSCHACH Então, eu estou tentando fazer um JOIN entre essas três tabelas..mas a questão é que preciso da pk do candidato para preencher a tabela Inscrição.. Mas essa pk é um dado inventado.. Não existe na tabela ENEM e nem em outra, só na candidato..

Comment: Aqui está o schema feito no dbdesigner -> http://i63.tinypic.com/2mmh9hc.png

Comment: Estou começando a achar que tem algo errado com a modelagem.. Só para vocês entenderem, a tabela enem está num banco a parte.. Ela é um "linguição" de dados do enem, contendo os dados do candidato e o da inscrição.. Porém a pk_candidato não está lá.. Apenas o número da inscrição

Comment: @MiuinWonderland Então o DB não foi bem projetado, você terá muitos problemas

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda, gente! Eu tive que mudar a modelagem e colocar a fk de inscrição dentro de candidato, por mais que seja errado... Foi o jeito que encontrei para funcionar. =/

Answer (score 1):

Seria interessante colocar também as informações da tabela ENEM, conforme fizeste com as de CANDIDATO e INSCRIÇÃO. Mas como diz que na tabela ENEM contém o campo inscrição, por este podemos fazer o join com INSCRIÇÃO e depois fazer um join com CANDIDATO.

Exemplo:

```
Select 
    c.PK_CANDIDATO 
FROM 
    ENEM e
    INNER JOIN INSCRIÇÃO i ON i.ID_INSCRIÇÃO = e.<CAMPO_DE_INSCRIÇÃO>
    INNER JOIN CANDIDATO c ON c.PK_CANDIDATO = i.FK_CANDIDATO

;
```

Nunca coloque nome de objetos com caracteres especiais como "Ç", "Ã".